# std::map <int,int> increment

Tags: c++, dictionary, increment

I'm trying to write a function that would return a prime factorisation of a given number (as part of solving project euler's problem #12). To count the prime factors. I use `std::map`.
The code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


bool IsPrime(unsigned int number)
{
    if (number < 1) return 0; // zero is not prime. For our purposes, one would be.
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i*i <= number; ++i)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int divisors(unsigned int num)
{
    int orig_num = num;
    std::map <int, int> primefactors; 
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
        if (num % i == 0 && IsPrime(i))
        {
            num /= i;
            ++primefactors[i];
            std::cout << primefactors[i] << "\t";
        }
    std::cout << orig_num << " = "; 
    for(auto& iter:primefactors)
         std::cout << iter.first <<  "^" << iter.second << " * ";
    return 0;   
}

int main()
{
    divisors(661500);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that all the counts of `primefactors` are returned as 1s, although the number in `main` was chosen specifically to be a product of primes to larger than 1 powers (661500 = 1^1*2^2*3^3*5^3*7^2).
My guess is that I'm incrementing something wrong.

Comment: `if (num % i == 0 && IsPrime(i))` should be `if (IsPrime(i)) while (num % i == 0)`

Comment: @AntonKovalenko, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dividing only once per prime. But you should continue dividing by the prime as long as number is divisible by it:

```
for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= num; ++i)
        if (IsPrime(i))
        {
            while (num % i == 0) {
                num /= i;
                ++primefactors[i];
                std::cout << primefactors[i] << "\t";
            }
        }
```

Actually there is no need for `IsPrime(i)` condition:

```
for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= num; ++i)
    while (num % i == 0) {
        num /= i;
        ++primefactors[i];
        std::cout << primefactors[i] << "\t";
    }
```

Proof: if `i` is not a prime, then condition `num % i == 0` implies that `num` is divisible by a prime factor `p` of `i`. But `p < i` so our loop had to go through `p` some time before `i`. And `while` loop would effectively erase all occurences of `p` in `num`. In particular by the time that `for` reaches `i` we have that `num` is no longer divisible by `p`. Contradiction. I.e. in the loop above if `num % i == 0` is satisfied, then `i` is prime.

Comment: Tried that, it resulted in just outputting numbers indefinitely.

Comment: @Chiffa Yeah, I've updated the code. You should start the loop from `2`. By the way: what you are doing is horribly inefficient. For example there is no need for `IsPrime(i)` condition at all.

Comment: Oh, that actually helped. Thanks. I guess I'll just work with 1 being considered a factor in another part of the code.

Comment: Why? I wish to find a prime factorisation, so I check whether I'm using prime factors.

Comment: @Chiffa I've updated the answer. Try removing it and see what happens. It's a version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for the proof, I see it now.